# How do i print the longest word in any given sentence without punctuation in Python?

Tags: python

I managed to have the output with the longest word, however it comes with a fullstop '.' at the end of the sentence. For example, my input is "You are great." and the output is "great." but i would like to remove the fullstop at the end. I've tried to use the no punctuation 'for' function but it results in a runtime error and other errors included. Does anyone have any idea how to correct it? Thanks! 
Edit: i've included my code below for reference. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ojL8.png)

Comment: Can you show us your code? It will be helpful to resolve the problem based on your code.

Comment: Use the `.rstrip()` method on a string to remove particular characters from the right hand side, e.g. `'great...'.rstrip('.') == 'great'`

Comment: I've edited my question and added my code. Hope this helps.

Comment: No you did not. An image is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all punctuation symbols, split the text by words and extract the longest word, for example:

```py
from string import punctuation


sample = "You are great."
for symbol in punctuation:
    sample = sample.replace(symbol, '')

longest_word = max(sample.split(), key=lambda word: len(word))
print(longest_word)

>>> great
```

Comment: This would have been my approach. `str.maketrans()` could be used to filter all punctuation symbols in one go. One should also consider whether a space is always present between two words where there is a punctuation symbol, because that might lead to unintended consequences.

Comment: @Reti43 I didn't know about `str.maketrans()`, thanks for sharing. This is a general solution, it should be updated according to the special needs of each case.

Answer (score 0):

One way of tackling it that's extensible for other punctuation that might give you an issue is to create a list of invalid characters. Then, use a for loop to replace any of them that you find in your string with an empty string. It's important to do it this way so that your method of finding the longest string is only counting actual letters and not the punctuation you are planning on removing.

```
invalid_chars = ['.',',','!','?']
s = "<your string here.>"


for c in invalid_chars:
    s.replcate(c,"")
longest_word = max(s.split(" "), key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you:

1. If you are only concerned with the "full stop" problem, you can remove it, for example: `sentence = sentence[:-1]`, which will remove the last character.
2. Or you may remove all the characters you don't want by replacing them as in: `sentence = sentence.replace('.', '')`

Comment: In the sentence `"Hello, how are you?"`, the longest word would be `"Hello,"`, so your first method would fail. You should also filter any punctuation symbols before counting the word lengths, because then the words `"you."` and `"this"` would be tied up.

Comment: You are correct, sir. I got fixed on the example, and we really should replace all the punctuations and not only the periods.